# Can localStorage do everything that cookies can do?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, local-storage

Can localStorage do everything that cookies can do?

I'm new to creating and storing custom cookies. I'm wondering what the differences are as localStorage looks like a good option.

Thanks.

Comment: yeah boom, it's deffo the better option  simple usage too - check the browsers that it is available for - http://caniuse.com/namevalue-storage

Comment: @boom: A little bit of research goes a long way... The link above is literally the first Google search result for "localStorage vs. cookies"